# How (or will) using black and white version of logo on main site be contra-productive?

Tags: website-design, logo, design-principles

A company I work for is in process of making a new website. Management wants to use only black and white version of our logo which primarily is colored.

The website will have a very minimalistic design and to tell the truth on such design black and white version of the logo looks better than the colored one.

Some people, including me, are concerned about using it. I never saw that company use black and white logo over the colored one, when there is absolutely no reason for that, we are not limited by printing factor and we can alter website design. Moreover, we never used black or white version until now.

Answer (score 1):

Not long ago, creating the b/w version of the logo or at least the monochromatic version, had its reason for possible future applications: forms sent by fax, photocopies, advertisements in one single-ink newspapers ... But nowadays all this sounds like it caming from another galaxy. A company for which I work and whose original logo with different gradients is my responsibility, in their last web they decided to put the logo in black. Of course I absolutely refused, but they have not paid any attention to me. This was a couple of years ago.

Today, when I see the logo only in black, I only see how well designed it is, much more readability, more immediacy, more clarity. I've even considered the redesign, not in black, but in a single flat ink.

Until recently, the great advantage of the advances in printed reproduction and of course the image on the screen, imposed the colors limitless in absolutely everything. Situation that designers love because the lack of limitations makes our work much easier. But the businessperson or companies that deal with their corporate image day by day feel saturated, hence their preference for immediacy, clarity, readability, white or black.

I don't think practicality is contra-productive.

[image]